# How to select more than 1 uniqueidentifier?

Tags: sql-server, select, uniqueidentifier

I would like to know if i can select more then 1 `uniqueidentifier` in `SQL server`.

To select 1 : `SELECT NEWID()` this brings back 1 result.

I would like to bring back like 50 results

**EDIT:**

I would like the results to be returned in 1 grid, so i can copy all of them at once. Not copy and paste 1 by 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to do this in SQL Server Management Studio?

Try:

```
SELECT NEWID()
GO 50
```

and run this batch

**Update:**

OK - how about this then??

```
SELECT NEWID()
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE name IS NULL
AND number < 50
```

Comment: This seems good, but is it possible to select them so the results get returned in 1 grid. I want to copy all of them into an excel sheet. I don't want to copy 1 by 1.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the `master.dbo.sysobjects` table has at least 50 system objects in it:

```
SELECT TOP 50 NEWID() FROM master.dbo.sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'S'
```

You don't need an order by, since the NEWID is random every time.

Comment: +1 really clever! I like it - much simpler than my second approach ;-)

Comment: @RemusRusanu - just wanted to make sure there were at least 50 records in there, since I wasn't sure how many non-system objects could be in the table, but it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
--run these queries independently
CREATE TABLE #temp1 (ID UniqueIdentifier)
GO

INSERT INTO #temp1
SELECT NewID() AS ID
GO 50

SELECT *
FROM #temp1
GO

DROP TABLE #temp1
GO
```